# make perl understand html comment "<!--" and "-->"

Tags: html, perl

How can I make perl understand html comment `<!--` and `-->` so when perl sees those code within the program, it will just simply ignores it and move to the next time?

The reason I am asking this is because, I have perl inside of the HTML and it would be a lot easier to edit and view those html templates if I can have perl code inside of the html comment `<!--` and `-->`.

Thanks!!

Comment: That would make it really hard to dump debug data into a commented out section of the document

Comment: What template system are you using?

Comment: Perhaps I am reading this wrong, but wouldn't this then expose the Perl logic to the reader. That sounds fine as long as your code is bulletproof (it isn't)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As redEvo noted in his answer, if the problem you're solving is running Perl code mixed with HTML to produce programmatically-generated HTML pages from a template, then the solution is to use one of the bunch of **existing Perl HTML templating solutions** (from Mason to Template Toolkit to HTML::Template to Embperl to full-fledged MVC frameworks) instead of trying to reinvent the bicycle.

Some of them (Embperl) are very similar to templating solutions in other languages syntax-wise (Embperl would look very familiar to JSP or ASP developer). Others have their own custom syntax.

You can choose from an assortment of solutions, some of the good lists/guides to assist are:

- [A very good Apache/mod_perl hosted guide to choosing a Templating System](http://perl.apache.org/docs/tutorials/tmpl/comparison/comparison.html)
- A fairly old (2001) but decent article "[Choosing a Templating System](http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/08/21/templating.html)" By Perrin Harkins

My personal recommendation is Embperl.

P.S. I'm not sure this warrants a bunch of downvotes, but it is not very clear as to WHY you need Perl code inside HTML comments. This what is known as XY problem - you're asking us how to do X to solve your problem Y, without telling what Y is, whereas most likely X is not the best (or even worst) solution to Y in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Perl has been around for a while, and there are plenty of tools to make Perl and HTML work well together. I don't know that simply commenting out Perl code within HTML is the best way to go. Do some research on what solution already exists that would be best for your situation. I've been reading about [Mason](http://masonbook.com), but there are definitely some lightweight [alternatives](http://masonbook.com/book/chapter-1.mhtml#TOC-ANCHOR-7).

Answer (score 2):

-1 for the idea.

But, if you really want to do this terrible idea - you should check the [perlfilter](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfilter.html) doc. You can do nearly anything with your perl source code, so, you can the `<!-- -->` comments into `#perl comments` before compilation...

My 2¢. Don't do this. You can embed perl into HTML with [Mason2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mason/). If you looking for an lightweight solution - it is the far best in these days, with modern perl bullets inserted - like Moose and PSGI. It is simple and powerful.